# Is it possible in c++ to forbid calling a certain function at compile time?

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes:

```
class Entity {
   void addChild(Entity* e);
};

class Control : public Entity {

};
```

What I want to do is to not allow adding a Control as a child of something that's not a Control. So, for example:

```
Control c;
Entity e;
e.addChild(c); // This line would throw an error (at compile time if possible);
```

The first thing I thought of is adding this to Entity:

```
void addChild(Control* c){
    assert(false);
};
```

NOTE: both Entity and Control are abstract classes but both has many subclasses.

But is there any way to get an error at compile time?

Comment: I'd suggest just redesigning your class hierarchy so that you don't inherent functions you don't ever want to use in derived classes.

Comment: Maybe you could make of `Entity` an *abstract class*, then it would be impossible to instanciate an Entity object.

Comment: I'm with sashang: if you need to expressly prohibit the use of a derived class as a base class, then there's a good chance that public inheritance is _not_ what you want to be doing. The main point of public inheritance is that you can use derived classes as base classes. If you have to forbid it, that's probably a problem in your class layout and design structure.

Answer (score 6):

You can declare the function, but don't implement it. That will give a linker error if you try to use it.

Comment: It still won't help if a control is added as a base class (Entity) pointer.

Comment: True, but that's more of a fundamental problem requiring a redesign.

Answer (score 2):

> void addChild(Control c){
>       assert(false);
>   };
>
> But is there any way to get an error at compile time?

You could use `static_assert` if your implementation has some C++11 support, or `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` that will work in any implementation. However, I would suggest you redesign your hierarchy appropiately. Also note that you are mixing pointers and objects in the definitions of `addChild` suggested.

Answer (score 2):

In C++0x, the mechanism you seek is indeed possible.

```
class Entity {
public:
  void addEntity(Entity*);
  void addEntity(Control*) = delete;
};
```

**But** it does not work as you would expect it!

```
int main() {
  Entity e;

  Control c;
  e.addEntity(&c); // ERROR

  Entity& ec = c;
  e.addEntity(&ec); // OK
}
```

As others have suggested, your use case is fishy. If you do not want `Control` classes to be passed as `Entity`, then remove the inheritance relationship. If you keep the inheritance relationship, then whenever an `Entity` is expected, a `Control` can be passed.

Answer (score 2):

With a little bit of template specialization, it can be somewhat be done.  But the only way I could make this work is by having the "addChild" method on the child element itself (renamed to "AttachToParent").  And passed by reference instead of by pointer.  Template specialization is hard!

```
class Entity
{
public:
    void AddChild(Entity* pChild);
};

class Control : public Entity
{

public:
    template <typename T>
    void AttachToParent(T& parent)
    {
        parent.You_are_trying_to_attach_Control_to_something_not_a_Control();
    }

    template <>
    void AttachToParent<Control>(Control& parent)
    {
        parent.AddChild(this);
    }
};



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Entity eParent;
   Entity eChild;
   Control cChild1;
   Control cChild2;

   eParent.AddChild(&eChild); // legal

   cChild2.AttachToParent(cChild1); // allowed
   //cChild1.AttachToParent(eParent); // uncomment this line and a compile error will occur

    return 0;
}
```